# Программа вызывает ошибку _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, исключения

Программа:

```
class Settlement {
    char* name;
    Land* land;
    int length;
public:
    Settlement() : length(1) {
        name = new char[8];
        strcpy(name, "noname");
        land = new Land[length];
    }
    Settlement(int newLength) : length(newLength) {
        name = new char[8];
        strcpy(name, "S");
        land = new Land[newLength];
    }
Land& operator [](int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > length) return *land;
        else return *(land + i);
    }


virtual ~Settlement() {
        if(name) delete[] name;
        delete[] land;
    };
void print() {
        cout << "Settlement " << name << " print:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            land[i].print();
        }
    }
```

Land - базовый класс, функция print() виртуальная.
Main():

```
Settlement s(3);
s[0] = l1;
s[1] = c1;
s[2] = b1; 
s.print();
```

l1 - объект класса Land;
c1, b1 - объекты классов-наследников land.
Программа вызывает ошибку _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

У Вас в классе есть голые указатели

```
char* name;
Land* land
```

а конструктор копирования/оператор присваивания не прописан. И он сгенерирован автоматически. Каждый раз, когда Вы пишите

```
s[0] = l1;
```

происходит вызов этих сгенерированных функций. А они просто копируют указатель.

Потом приходит время деструкторов и первый объект разрушает свои вложенные переменные. Вот когда второй пытается разрушить... вот тут и получается Ваша ошибка.

Что делать?

- Почитать о правиле [трех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))/пяти и написать недостающие функции (конструктор копий и оператор копирования).
- Либо писать на с++, а не си (правда есть некоторые преподаватели, которым это не нравится). То есть, вместо `char*` использовать `std::string`, а вместо `Land* land;` использовать `std::vector<Land>` (это самый красивый способ, плюс он поможет избежать чехарды с `strcpy` и другими штуками с ручным выделением памяти).
- Либо пойти дальше и использовать умные указатели (`unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr`), но в данной ситуации они излишние.

Comment: Settlement(Settlement& temp) : length(temp.length) {
        name = new char[strlen(temp.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, temp.name);
        land = new Land[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            land[i] = temp.land[i];
        }
    } Напсиал такое копирование и не работает.

Comment: Позвольте, присваивание   s[0] = l1;  как  связано с вызовом  конструктора  копирования или оператора присваивания класса  Settlement? А класс  Land тут не представлен. Тут скорее дело в устаревшем strcpy

Comment: @ChuckBortowski, а как вы конструирует объекты временные? Небось как-то так? `Land l1 = Land...`

Comment: Land l1(name, x, y);